# Tradingview Pine script `strategy.exit` and `strategy.close` don't respect `from_entry` value

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading, cryptocurrency

I have several different entries in my strategy, and I want to assign separate stop losses to them:

```
// @version=4
strategy("Test strategy")
strategy.entry("E0", strategy.long, limit=10000, when=close[1] > 10000)
strategy.entry("E1", strategy.long, limit=10000, when=close[1] > 10000)
strategy.exit("SL-E0", "E0", stop=9000)
strategy.exit("SL-E1", "E1", stop=9500)
```

As far as I understand the documentation ([https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_strategy{dot}exit](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dexit)) the 2nd parameter of `strategy.exit` should cause the exit to apply only to the matching entry, however looking at the trade list (when applied to `BTCUSD` on a 2h timeframe - for reference) I see this:

```
1   Entry Long  E0      2019-07-02 14:00    10000.0 
    Exit Long   SL-E1   2019-07-17 02:00    9500.0
2   Entry Long  E1      2019-07-02 14:00    10000.0
    Exit Long   SL-E0   2019-09-25 04:00    9000.0
```

So the wrong stop loss is being applied. Is this a bug? I have tried numerous different configurations of the exit call, including `loss` instead of `stop`, as well as pulling the condition external:

```
if low < 9000
    strategy.exit("SL-E0", "E0")
```

All have the same effect whereby "SL-E1" causes "E0" to exit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
// @version=4
strategy("Test strategy", close_entries_rule="ANY")
strategy.entry("E0", strategy.long, limit=10000, when=close[1] > 10000)
strategy.entry("E1", strategy.long, limit=10000, when=close[1] > 10000)
strategy.exit("SL-E0", "E0", stop=9000)
strategy.exit("SL-E1", "E1", stop=9500)
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrey-d! That makes sense now. Its a pity that option isn't documented in the pine reference. For anyone else wanting more information, there's this https://kodify.net/tradingview/strategy-settings/close-entries-rule/.

Answer (score 0):

in the entry , you should have the price you target for your TP en SL
something like `limit=close+10000*syminfo.mintick` and `stop=close-10000*syminfo.mintick`
in case of a long position

and in the exit, you should directly put the ticks
`stop=9000` (it's like 900 pips, it's huge)